# Programmatically search formatted text in Word document and surround with tags

Tags: c#, search, replace, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using Word interop with C# to convert a set of Word documents to HTML. These conversions require a couple of manual interventions which is why I'm creating this "middle station" where the necessary adjustments can be made. And all the fully automatic conversion tools I've find create a lot of inline styling and other things I don't want. One thing I'd like to handle automatically, though, is to find all text parts in italics and surround them by < em > tags (or maybe rather replace them with the same text surrounded by tags).

I have read what they have to say here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx (for example "Use a Find object to loop through a Microsoft Office Word document and search for specific text, formatting, or style") and I know how to find one text and replace it with another, but I haven't been able to figure out how to find formatting to begin with, let alone how to insert other text around it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: I tried a regex (https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f) but it doesn't seem like placeholders work in interop. Otherwise something like this could have worked (if the placeholder hadn't been interpreted as an unknown escape sequence):

```
findObject.Text = "(*)";
findObject.Font.Italic = 1;
findObject.Replacement.Text = "<em>\1</em>";
```

Edit 2:
I may be on the right track, but there are two problems left. This code shows me each italic word one after another:

```
Range rng = doc.Range();
rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
object missing = Type.Missing;
rng.Find.Font.Italic = 1;

while(rng.Find.Execute("<*>",
    ref missing, ref missing, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing)) {
        rng.Select();
        string txt = application.Selection.Text;
        application.Selection.Text.Replace(txt, "<em>" + txt + "</em>");
        application.Selection.InsertBefore("<em>");
        MessageBox.Show(application.Selection.Text);
}
```

Then I assumed that I could do something like this:

```
application.Selection.InsertBefore("<em>");
application.Selection.InsertAfter("</em>");
```

or this:

```
string txt = application.Selection.Text;
application.Selection.Text.Replace(txt, "<em>" + txt + "</em>");
```

But in the first case Visual Studio basically freezes (or takes forever), in the second case nothing is replaced.

So problem No 1 is how to replace the selection in this context.
Problem No 2 is how to make the regex select complete italic strings, not just single words. Using @ after * to indicate "one or more" returns one character at a time and it doesn't seem to be possible to make it greedier. But the second problem is easy to solve afterwards (in post-interop mode) if I just get those tags into the text.

Yet another edit:

application.Selection.InsertBefore("X"); does indeed work if I stick to letters and numbers. As soon as I try to insert < or other special characters used in Word-style regular expressions it becomes extremely slow. So maybe I'll just use some guaranteed unique combinations and replace them later, such as "ssttaarrtt" and "eenndd". Silly. :)

Comment: have you tried using range.find with the regexp and the use the methods insertBefore and insertAfter ?

Comment: I didn't see your question until I'd posted my last edit. I suppose the answer is yes if I understand you correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick and dirty solution.

for each character in the document

Create a [range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a9dt54a.aspx) of the character (document.range(character,character+1))

Use [Range.italic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821583%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to check if the range is italic.

If it is italic insert before this character a "< em >" and set a flag (EM_FLAG) that you are in a < em > tag.

if it is not italic and the flag EM_FLAG is set insert after "< /em >"

ugly but I think it should work.

Comment: Yes, it's working but unfortunately it's much too slow.